# IDA 7.0 (freeware) auto-analysis gets stuck in a loop

Tags: ida, assembly, deobfuscation

I am trying to create a graph so that I can visualize the flow of a particular function in a game that I am interested in. I was initially using Cheat Engine to follow the flow of the function, but after going through about 20 jmps to finally get to the ret instruction, I decided to open up the executable in IDA so that I could see the graph view.

When I opened the executable in IDA, I ran into an issue where the auto-analysis gets "stuck" in a loop, never finishing.

Looking at the code, I do wonder if there is some sort of obfuscation going on, because it seems like the same thing could be coded in a far lesser number of instructions.

What should I do?

Here is an example of a piece of the code that I suspect is causing an issue (sorry if my comments don't make much sense):

```
cmp [rcx],rdi             ; if *rcx == rdi:
cmove eax,r15d            ; do eax = r15d
add rcx,08                ; rcx += 8
dec rdx                   ; i -= 1
mov [rsp-08],rbp          ; var a = rbp
lea rsp,[rsp-08]          ; rsp = &a
mov rbp,game.exe+13139A0  ; rbp = game.exe+13139A0
xchg [rsp],rbp            ; swap(a, rbp) i.e.
                          ;   a = game.exe+13139A0
                          ;   rbp = rbp (original value)
lea rsp,[rsp-08]          ; var b; rsp = &b
mov [rsp],rbx             ; b = rbx
lea rsp,[rsp-08]          ; var c; rsp = &c
mov [rsp],rax             ; c = rax
mov rbx,[rsp+10]          ; rbx = a
mov rax,game.exe+1313990  ; rax = game.exe+1313990
cmovne rbx,rax            ; rbx = i == 0 ? rax : rbx
mov [rsp+10],rbx          ; a = rbx
lea rsp,[rsp+08]          ; rsp = &b
mov rax,[rsp-08]          ; rax = c
mov rbx,[rsp]             ; rbx = b
lea rsp,[rsp+08]          ; rsp = &a
lea rsp,[rsp+08]          ; rsp = &???
jmp qword ptr [rsp-08]    ; jmp a i.e.
                          ;   i == 0: game.exe+1313990
                          ;   i != 0: game.exe+13139A0
```

Comment: The code is obfuscated by Arxan GuardIT. If IDA is actually infinitely looping here, that's a bug, which might also affect the 7.x commercial line. If so, Hex-Rays might fix it upstream and could possibly release a new freeware build. But, given that Hex-Rays states on the freeware download page that this version "comes without technical support", they probably won't reply to a support mail. Your best and only option is to hope an IDA developer sees and confirms this, reproduces it in commercial builds, fixes it, and releases a new freeware. I wouldn't hold my breath for a freeware update.

Comment: Which game is it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Undefining the code piece, which makes autoanalysis stuck, usually helps. You can always return to this part and make it code again after autoanalysis is complete.